# SQL SUM group by having SUM

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got this structure table:

```
USER_ID | POINTS_BALANCE

10     |  180          
10     |  20               
10     |  100                 
10     |  120
```

How can I UPDATE points_balance field for example to 500 for all this users:

```
select user_id, sum(points_balance)
from `user_points_table`
group by user_id
having SUM(points_balance) >= 400 && SUM(points_balance) <= 499
```

Or can I INSERT a new ROW for `user_id` that `having sum(points_balance)` between 400 and 499?

EDIT:

For example:

```
select user_id, sum(points_balance)
from `user_points_table`
where user_id = 74
group by user_id
having SUM(points_balance) >= 400 && SUM(points_balance) <= 499
```

Result:

```
USER_ID | POINTS_BALANCE
74      |  434 <-- How can I update this result to 500?
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide the results you are looking for.

Comment: can you explain more what's the problem you're having

Comment: So, do you want to increase 1 of the rows (if so, which row?), or add a new row, to increase it to 500?

Comment: You want the SUM() to equal 500? If that's what you want then you need to decide how the "extra" points will be allocated among the various rows for the user.

Comment: Thank you all. I've update my own question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: No, it's not clearer.  Do you want to actually update the table or do you just want to display 500 in the results?  If just display, change your select statement to return 500 instead of the sum.  If you want to update, are you wanting to update or insert -- and if update, which row?

Comment: @TomH the SUM() has to be equal to `500` exactly. My idea was to insert in the last record the result of this expression: `500 - SUM(points_balance)`.

Comment: @sgeddes Hello, I want to UPDATE the table.

Comment: @Sean my idea was to do the `UPDATE`, I don't know if it's easier to `INSERT` a new row in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to add new a new row to the table, one option is to use `insert into select`:

```
insert into user_points_table 
select user_id, 500-sum(points_balance)
from `user_points_table`
where user_id = 74
group by user_id
having SUM(points_balance) >= 400 && SUM(points_balance) <= 499;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8e69/1)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This return `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the information you derived. If you are looking to display a different number from what you derived, you can do this:

```
select 
  user_id, 
  case 
  when totals < 500 then 500 
  else totals 
  end as totals 
from (
  select user_id, sum(points_balance) as totals 
  from test 
  -- where user_id = 10
  group by user_id 
  having totals between 400 and 499
) t
-- where user_id = 10;

+---------+--------+
| user_id | totals |
+---------+--------+
|      10 |    500 |
+---------+--------+
```

If the result of

```
select user_id, sum(points_balance) as totals 
from test 
-- where user_id = 10
group by user_id 
having totals between 400 and 499;
```

is

```
+---------+--------+
| user_id | totals |
+---------+--------+
|      10 |    420 |
+---------+--------+
```

and you want to bump this up to 500, you know that the difference between 500 and 420 is 80. So, insert a new record:

```
insert into test (user_id, points_balance) values (10, 80);
```

or you can update one of the records to:

```
update test set points_balance = points_balance + 80
where user_id = 10 and points_balance = 120;
```

The question follows - which of the many records for 10 will you update? I hope you have an id to uniquely identify each row. If you have that, update the row with lowest id. If you don't have a field that uniquely identifies each row, this would be a good time to create one such field.

In order to do this all in one shot, you would build a stored procedure or write a script in PHP/Python/whatever language you feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

As I understand your question, you are looking for a way to set every users points to minimum of 500 by adding the difference.
So, your solution might look like the following:

```
mysql> DELIMITER //;
-> CREATE PROCEDURE updateMinimum()
-> BEGIN
-> DECLARE u,s INT;
-> DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
-> SELECT user_id, SUM(points) FROM user_points GROUP BY user_id;
-> OPEN cur;
-> read_loop: LOOP
->    FETCH cur INTO u,s;
->    IF s < 500 THEN
->        INSERT INTO user_points (user_id, points) VALUES (u, 500-s);
->    END IF;
-> END LOOP;
-> CLOSE cur;
-> END//
mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> CALL updateMinimum();
```

It will tell you there's `No data`, but don't mind - it did the trick. Just use `SELECT` to check it out:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(points) FROM user_points GROUP BY user_id;
```

You may use `CALL updateMinimum()` whenever you want, anytime.
Or if you don't need it anymore you can remove it by `DROP PROCEDURE updateMinimum();`

Comment: How can i limit it `IF s >= 400 && IF s <= 499`?

By the way It return `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur FOR SELECT user_id, SUM(points_balance) FROM `user_points_table' at line 2`.

Comment: You can limit it by changing `IF s < 500 THEN` to `IF s >= 400 AND s <= 499 THEN`. And the syntax error should not present if declaration goes after `BEGIN`.

Comment: Using this:

`DECLARE cur FOR SELECT user_id, SUM(points_balance) FROM user_points GROUP BY user_id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
BEGIN
OPEN cur;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO u,s;
    IF s >= 400 AND s <= 499 THEN
        INSERT INTO user_points (user_id, points_balance) VALUES (u, 500-s);
    END IF;
CLOSE cur;
END;`

It result: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CLOSE cur' at line 1`.

Comment: @simo, oops, my bad. I've just edited my answer, so now it 100% works.

Comment: It returns `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql> CALL updateMinimum()' at line 1`. I copied and pasted into **SQL Query** but unfortunately It doesn't seem to work for me.

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8e69/6)

Comment: You don't have to copy-paste it. At least type `DELIMITER` strings separetely. You can copy-paste the part between `CREATE PROCEDURE` and `END//`, but check the names of the table and fields.